Binary excel file(.xlsb) is not opening or corrupted after creating using Apache POI in Spring boot
I'm trying to generate excel binary file(.xlsb) using Apache POI in the Spring boot. File successfully created. However, when I try to open the file, I receive the following error.
"Excel cannot open the file '202107-usagereportb.xlsb' because the file format or file extension is not valid."
Has anyone ever created binary excel file using Apache POI and Spring boot? If so, how?
Here is the code I am using.
ByteArrayOutputStream bios = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(bios);

byte[] ba = bios.toByteArray();

String OWCCb = fromDate.replace("-", "").substring(0, 6)+"- 
"+"usagereportb;
        
FileOutputStream outputStream1 = new FileOutputStream(new 
File("D:\\java\\rating-report\\usage_report_v1\\"+OWCCb+".xlsb"));

workbook.write(outputStream1);
outputStream1.close();


Many things can corrupt a file, but most relevant here would be how you've created it and how  you're trying to read it. Perhaps you will want to show the relevant [mre] code, no?

don't think you can just take the bytes of the workbook.  xslb would store each cell's data in binary format.  Other than that I think it's still XML... and just as an xslx file, that's zipped.  I'd use xslx and be done with it.  The only benefit of xslb would be time to open the file.

if POI doesn't support writing xlsb files, another option would be to go through Excel's com control (open xlsx file, save as xlsb file), but it'll be pretty clunky and might also cause some concurrency issues if multiple calls are made.  (It'd be something like:   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application().ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(NewEndFile, XlFileFormat.xlExcel12, m, m, m, m, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, m, m, m, m, m);

Apache POI doesn't have support for writing XLSB files.... https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/XLSBUnsupportedException.html

Is there any open-source Java library that we can utilize to implement a binary Excel file in Java?

@Akshay - recommendations are off-topic here.
